# Loading More Results From Database Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the problem that the screen scrolls at every time directly down to the bottom, i change this line

```
$("body,html").animate({scrollTop: $("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 800);
```

into

```
$("body").animate({scrollTop: $("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 800);
```

now on firefox its start at the top, but with chrome desktop, on mobile android/ios or ipad tablet its start again scrolling directly to the botton, has someone an idea ?

my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="results"><!-- results appear here --></ul>
<div align="center">
<button id="load_more_button"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" class="animation_image" style="float:left;"> Load More</button>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var track_page = 1; 
load_contents(track_page);

$("#load_more_button").click(function (e) {
track_page++;
load_contents(track_page);
});

function load_contents(track_page){
$('.animation_image').show();

$.post( 'index2_data.php', {'page': track_page}, function(data){

    if(data.trim().length == 0){
        $("#load_more_button").text("No more records!").prop("disabled", true);
    }

    $("#results").append(data);
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: $("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 800);
    $('.animation_image').hide(); 
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you not want it to scroll in any browser? Why not just remove that `animate` line entirely? Some browsers recognize body for scroll, some only html; for those that recognize body scroll you are still telling them to scroll so the top of the page is at the top of the `#load_more_button` button, which appears to be the last element on the page (hence the scroll to bottom effect).

Comment: "the screen scrolls at every time directly down to the bottom" is there any other content after #load_more_button button.

Comment: Your question is _unclear_. Do you want the screen scroll or not?

Comment: your are right, simply remove the line works, thank you